# How to Flip the triangle?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

[How to flip this triangle?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCE5G.png)

So i was making aritmethic sequance triangle. It was upside down.
How do I turn it 180 degree?

for example:

```
1=1
1+2=3
1+2+3=6
etc...
```

my code:

```
package javaapplication4;

public class NewClass5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=5,a; 
        for(int j=i; j>=1; j--) { 
            for(a=1; a<=i; a++)
                System.out.print(a +" + ");
            int n = 0;
           for(a = 1; a<=i; a++) { 
               n = n + a;
           }
           System.out.print(" = "+ n);
           System.out.println();
           i--; 
       } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it for any n, by getting input from the user

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int add = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
            if (j == i) 
                System.out.print("=");
            else 
                System.out.print("+");    
            add += j;    
        }
        System.out.println(add);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your help.
I have a question, though. how would you do the operation like this in reverse order?

I mean, instead of 1*3*5

I want them in reverse order like 5*3*1.

I still don't have any clue.

Comment: you want a pattern like 5*3*1 being the 1st row? here 5*3*1 will be the only row if we take bigger No., then the loop would start

Comment: Yeah. something like

7+5+3+1=16

5+3+1=9

3+1=4

1=1

Comment: I am ready with the solution, please ask another question so others are also benefitted, inform me when posted another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change the sequence of loop from descending to ascending, rest of the things should be the same:

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(j);
        if (j == i) 
            System.out.print("=");
        else 
            System.out.print("+");    
        sum += j;    
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

When I run this, I'm able to see expected output:

```
src : $ java NewClass5 
1=1
1+2=3
1+2+3=6
1+2+3+4=10
1+2+3+4+5=15
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
Now I got it.

Thanks for your help